# Apply Edits on ArcGIS not updating geometry

Tags: geometry, arcgis-platform

I am using this command on ArcGIS

```
curl --location 'https://services8.arcgis.com/xxxx/arcgis/rest/services/SM2/FeatureServer/0/applyEdits' \
--header 'X-Esri-Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx__Xi5nYnjc_ST9Kou0fOq9ps90N4D-0hi5yJbhFXbTnZv0Y9-vrSB24DpwVmaWB8lkneyO3s9iXrPW5jTOAGohHsVJ9HhRhwd8LCzuwUCh6DJdFN7L5usNLOA_hNemeId4oEzW0nvW7v-FPDXiINqS4eDCTmHcjnlDU6ZgAv' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'f=pjson' \
--data-urlencode 'adds=[{"geometry":{"x":-118.15,"y":33.80},"attributes":{"OWNER":"JoeSmith","VALUE":94820.37,"APPROVED":true,"LASTUPDATE":1227663551096,"GlobalID":"{74100804-E229-49b8-8CDC-9B5D3EF03EDA}"}},{"geometry":{"x":-118.37,"y":34.086},"attributes":{"OWNER":"JohnDoe","VALUE":17325.90,"APPROVED":false,"LASTUPDATE":1227628579430,"GlobalID":"{39B856DC-AFE4-4c02-B433-A9361ACD91CF}"}}]'
```

I got example from: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/apply-edits-feature-service-layer-.htm

and this is response:

```
{
  "addResults": [
      {
          "objectId": 13,
          "uniqueId": 13,
          "globalId": null,
          "success": true
      },
      {
          "objectId": 14,
          "uniqueId": 14,
          "globalId": null,
          "success": true
      }
  ],
  "updateResults": [],
  "deleteResults": []
}
```

Problem is that on ArcGIS Visualisation tab, I don't see that geometry is added.
I see values in table, but not on map.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: This doesn’t look like ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap 10.0 so I removed those tags.

Comment: What is the *ArcGIS Visualisation tab*? If that's in a browser, check if the new feature loads in a private window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing spatialReference:

```
          geometry: {
            x: item.lng,
            y: item.lat,
            spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 },
          }
```

with spatialReference it works fine